# Linq extended set operations

Tags: c#, linq, hashset

**Current situation :**

`HashSet<string> MasterSet => {100, 3}`

`HashSet <string> SubSet => {100, 3} or {100} or {100, 3, 1}`

So from the huge list of subsets, based on MasterSet I select the particular set like this:

`if(MasterSet.SetEquals(subSet) || MasterSet.IsSupersetOf(subSet) || MasterSet.IsSubsetOf(subSet))`

Process with that subSet if it is true otherwise loop through other available sets.

**Problem with duplicates :**
If business logic wants to include duplicate in Master set and subset like :

`MasterSet => {100, 3, 3}`

`SubSet => {100, 3, 3} or {100, 3} or {100, 3, 3, 1}`

then HashSet usage is deprived.

How do I select the subset if I change the MasterSet and Subset to `List<string>`

**EDIT :**
Solution provided by "BigYellowCactus" works. However if I wantto use headers instead of order of element to match would it be even easier to filter the set?

```
MasterSet => {100, 3, 4}
MasterHeaders => {"T","F","V"} //Headers element corresponds to the MasterSet element
```

Case 1:

```
SubSet => {3, 100}
SubSetHeaders => {"F", "T"} //Headers element corresponds to the SubSet element
```

Case 2:

```
SubSet => {4, 3}
SubSetHeaders => {"V", "F"} //Headers element corresponds to the SubSet element
```

Is it possible to first match by headers comparing MasterHeaders and SubSetHeaders and then Match by values?

Comment: Is your question, "Is there an implementation of `ISet<string>` that allows duplicate members?" That is your question as I understand it, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) extension method.

**Description**

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

---

**Example:**

```
if (MasterSet.All(e => SubSet.Contains(e)) || SubSet.All(e => MasterSet.Contains(e)))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

---

**Alternative:**

```
if (!MasterSet.Except(SubSet).Any() || !SubSet.Except(MasterSet).Any())
{
    //do stuff
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Just for the case you want to `SubSet { 100, 3, 3 }` *not* match `MasterSet = { 100, 100, 3 }` as Iridium pointed out in his comment, you can go by simple counting the occurring of each element.

```
if (MasterSet.All(e => MasterSet.Count(r => r==e) <= SubSet.Count(r => r==e))
    || SubSet.All(e => SubSet.Count(r => r==e) <= MasterSet.Count(r => r==e)))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

(Note that this is probably not the most efficient way...)

---

**Edit2:**

Given that you basically search a sequence inside a sequence, you can use the following method:

```
void Main()
{
    var MasterSet = new List<string>() {"100", "3","4"};

    var SubSets = new[] 
    {
        new List<string>() {"100", "100", "3"},
        new List<string>() {"100", "3", "4"},
        new List<string>() {"32", "3423", "4234", "100", "3", "4", "34234"},
        new List<string>() {"100", "32", "3423", "4234", "100", "3", "4", "34234"},
        new List<string>() {"100", "32", "3", "4234", "100", "4", "34234"},
        new List<string>() {"100", "4", "3"},
        new List<string>() {"100", "3", "3"},
        new List<string>() {"100", "3"},
        new List<string>() {"100", "3", "3", "1"}
    };

    foreach (var SubSet in SubSets)
    {
        if (IsMatch(MasterSet, SubSet))
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", SubSet) + " is a \"subset\"");
        else if (IsMatch(SubSet, MasterSet))
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", SubSet) + " is a \"superset\"");
    }
}

bool IsMatch<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> to_test)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    using (var sub_enumerator = to_test.GetEnumerator())
        while (sub_enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                return false;
            if (!enumerator.Current.Equals(sub_enumerator.Current))
                sub_enumerator.Reset();
        }
    return true;
}
```

**Output:**

> 100, 3, 4 is a "subset"
>   32, 3423, 4234, 100, 3, 4, 34234 is a "superset"
>   100, 32, 3423, 4234, 100, 3, 4, 34234 is a "superset"
>   100, 3 is a "subset"

Comment: If I'm understanding the intention correctly, this would incorrectly return true if say, MasterSet = { 100, 100, 3 } and SubSet was { 100, 3, 3 } - whilst all of the elements in SubSet exist in MasterSet and vice versa, MasterSet is neither a superset nor subset of SubSet (at least given the definitions I'd expect of those two operations with not-necessarily-unique elements).

Comment: This has to be answered by Suresh if this is what he wants or not, since strictly speaking the set of `100`, `100`, `3` is `100`, `3` while the set of `100`, `3`, `3` is also `100`, `3`....

Comment: You can't count elements in a `HashSet` like that - you'll either get 1 or 0.

Comment: @Rawling The questioneer wants to use Lists.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus: Thanks it works. But now I need to break my head if the list of subset contains sets like this { (100,3,4), (100,4,3)} and MasterSet is { (100, 4, 3) }. It fetch the first one as it satisfies all conditions.

Comment: @Suresh So the order of the items is important too?

Comment: @BigYellowCactus: Yes order of items is very important. Is it solvable?

Comment: @Sureh Given a MasterSet of (100, 4, 3), is a SubSet of (100, 99, 4, 22, 3) a match or not?

Comment: @BigYellowCactus: it is not match. In this case the matches are (100, 4, 3) / (100, 4) / (100) or (100, 4, 3, .....)

Comment: @BigYellowCactus: I upvoted your answer. Also I've edited the question to go for hassle free solution. Please have look at it & guide me.

Answer (score 0):

The current framework implementations of [`ISet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iset-1?view=net-6.0) are `HashSet<T>` and `SortedSet<T>`. Both of these classes enforce member uniqueness and do not allow duplicates.

Whilst this may first seem like an omission in the framework, it is actually related to the properties and defenition of a mathematical set. As explained in [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20171222072410/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65580.html), a mathematical set does not have duplicate members and logicaly `{100, 3}` is equivalent to `{100, 3, 3}.`

It may be possible to extend `List<T>` to implement `ISet<T>`, perhaps calling the new class `Sack<T>` but, the non unique implementation of the `ISet<T>` will be siginificantly more challenging than those exisiting in the framework, without putting much thought into it, it seems reminiscient of general [Knapsack problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).